# Indexing multidimensional table using column vector

Tags: r

I have contingency tables of varying sizes. I'd like to index them using a set of values from a dataset. However, 
`myTable[c(5,5,5,5)]` clearly does not do what I want. How do I get `c(5,5,5,5)` to read as `myTable[5,5,5,5]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on @ttmaccer's answer: this works because of the (slightly) obscure paragraph in `?"["` that reads:

```
When indexing arrays by ‘[’ a single argument ‘i’ can be a
matrix with as many columns as there are dimensions of ‘x’;
the result is then a vector with elements corresponding to
the sets of indices in each row of ‘i’.
```

The effect of using `t(ii)` in

```
ii <- c(5,5,5,5)
a[t(ii)]
```

is to convert `ii` to a 1x4 matrix that `[` interprets as a matrix as described above; `a[matrix(ii,nrow=1)]` would be more explicit but less compact.

The nice thing about this approach (besides avoiding the magical-seeming aspects of `do.call`) is that it works in parallel for more than one set of indices, as in

```
jj <- matrix(c(5,5,5,5,
               6,6,6,6),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
a[jj]
## [1] 4445 5556
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding on @ttmacer's answer. Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your question, this construct, using `do.call()`, should do what you want:

```
## Create an example array and a variable containing the desired index
a <- array(1:1e4, dim = c(10, 10, 10, 10))
ii <- c(5, 5, 5, 5)

## Use do.call to extract the desired element.
do.call("[", c(list(a), ii))
# [1] 4445
```

The call above works because the following are all equivalent:

```
a[5, 5, 5, 5]
`[`(a, 5, 5, 5, 5)
do.call("[", list(a, 5, 5, 5, 5))
do.call("[", c(list(a), ii))
```